# Jenkins Mac Xamarin UI Test failed

Tags: android, macos, xamarin, jenkins, continuous-integration

I install jenkins on my mac and I would like to launch Xamarin UI Test Android and IOS. Except that when I run the testes android with Jenkins (I use the plugin android emulator) I get errors, the problem is that sometimes 2/3 of the tests will work, sometimes no .. I specify that on windows everything works, or that if I open the simulator myself with visual and I run just nunit command line it works too.I also disable the view because otherwise it does not build. Here is the error: [Error test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUVUY.png)

Jenkins command line :

> mono /Users/Shared/opt/NUnit/nunit3-console.exe /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/build_project/UITest/bin/Debug/UITest.dll

And i also have this in the log :

> _RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

i resolve issue with add : Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AppDataMode.DoNotClear in my start app

```
 return ConfigureApp.Android.EnableLocalScreenshots().ApkFile("/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/build_project/AppTest/AppTest.Android/bin/Debug/com.companyname.AppTest.apk").StartApp(Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AppDataMode.DoNotClear);
```